# Reverse the content of the file from beginning to end in Python

Tags: python

I am carrying out an investigation on some files I have seen on my family's computer. They are long files of mainly text content but the content appears to be reversed, i.e. instead of www.google.com it is moc.elgoog.www. There are lots of non-ASCII characters in the file as well.

I'm thinking python would be the best on this computer to try and parse the files so they read normally and I can find out what they are doing here.

Thanks!

Comment: will it work if you read the file in reverse order?

Comment: for small files this should work  `with open('spam.txt') as f:  spam = f.read()[::-1]`

Comment: how big are the files you need to process?

Comment: The files range from 1MB to 5MB.

Answer (score 4):

Write bytes in reverse order:

```
import os

bufsize = 1 << 15
with open('file.in', 'rb') as f, open('file.out', 'wb') as fout:
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) # move to the end of file
    for pos in reversed(xrange(0, f.tell(), bufsize)):
        f.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)
        fout.write(f.read(bufsize)[::-1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much J.F. Sebastian. This has worked a treat, preserving the non-ASCII bytes as well. Hope they are not endian dependant! Looks to be a malware/spyware-log. Time to flatten and rebuild.

Comment: This is not very 'pythonic', but what we're trying to achieve is not very pythonic either. I guess you could prettify it with a generator function or something, but this is much simpler. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks! It's save my afternoon! Note: it must change to `range` instead of `xrange` if using python3.

Comment: @LianSheng: I didn't use `range()` because it returns a list in Python 2 (it would make the algorithm O(n) in memory while the current version is O(1) in memory). On Python 3, you can use `range()` (it doesn't return a list there)

Answer (score 3):

quick and dirty ditty:

```
f = open(filename, "rb")
s = f.read()
f.close()
f = open(output_filename, "wb")
f.write(s[::-1])
f.close()
```

might be better to just reverse the output of `strings`, though.

Comment: As J.F. Sebastian says, I get the following error message with this. `TypeError: must be a string or buffer, not reversed`

Comment: Should be: `f.write(''.join(reversed(s)))`.

Comment: You're right, reversed doesn't do what I expect it to. I must admit, I'm not Dutch.

Answer (score 2):

If these files are not too large (i.e. they fit into RAM), you can do:

```
for fn in list_of_original_files:
    open(fn+'_reversed', 'w').write(reversed(open(fn).read()))
```

or safer:

```
for fn in list_of_original_files:
    with open(fn, 'r') as r:
        with open(fn+'_reversed', 'w') as w:
            w.write(reversed(r.read()))
```

Comment: `write(reversed())` produces `TypeError: must be string or buffer, not reversed`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your files fit in memory (twice):

```
from os import fsync
import mmap

def reverse(fw_file_path, bw_file_path):
  with open(fw_file_path, 'rb')as fw_file:
    fw_file_map = mmap.mmap(fw_file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    with open(bw_file_path, "wb") as bw_file:
      bw_file.write(''.join([c for c in reversed(fw_file_map)]))
      bw_file.flush()
      fsync(bw_file.fileno())
    fw_file_map.close()
```

The mmap() improves speed very noticeably on both my Windows and Linux machines compared to the other approach. If files are too big you could experiment with chunking them before and cat'ing them after applying reverse().